# how to convert a sequential function to parallele execution in nodejs v6

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, async-await

I am using nodejs v6 and hence there is no default support for async/await. I am trying to use callback model for this. I have 2 separate functions which I want to combine to run parallelly:

## Function1:

```
function getUserWidgets1(query, getUserWidgetsCallback) {
    var finalResult = {};
    var userPreferencesDatabaseObject = dbs.userpreferencedbstart("User Preferences: get Widgets ");
    userPreferencesDbHelper.getUserWidgets(userPreferencesDatabaseObject, query, function(result, err){
        dbs.userpreferencedbstop
        (userPreferencesDatabaseObject, 
            "getUserWidgets");
        if(err){
            logger.error(err);
            getUserWidgetsCallback(null, err);
        }else {
            finalResult.data = result.rows;
            getUserWidgetsCallback(finalResult, null);
        }
    });
}
```

## Function 2:

```
    function getAllDefaultWidgets(query, getAllDefaultWidgetsCallback) {
    var finalResult = {};
    var userPreferencesDatabaseObject = dbs.userpreferencedbstart("User Preferences: get widgets lists");
    userPreferencesDbHelper.getAllDefaultWidgets(userPreferencesDatabaseObject, query, function(result, err){
        dbs.userpreferencedbstop(userPreferencesDatabaseObject, "getAllDefaultWidgets");
        if(err) {
            logger.error(err);
            getAllDefaultWidgetsCallback(null, err);
        }else {
            finalResult.data = result.rows;
            getAllDefaultWidgetsCallback(finalResult, null);
        }
    })
}
```

I am basically trying to combine both the functions using async.parallel (to run parallelly) and return output form both the function something like this {userWidgets: "somedata", defaultWidgets: "some more data"} and hence was trying to convert in below format... but I am confused how to do this. I know using async/ await its very simple, but i cant use that.

## Combined function:

```
function getUserWidgetsAndDefaultWidget(query, getUserWidgetsCallback) {
    console.log("GOD:: Called.... ");
    async.parallel([
        function(callback) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                callback(null, 'one');
            }, 100);
        },
        function(callback) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                callback(null, 'two');
            }, 100);
        }
    ],
    function(err, results) {
        // has result ['one', 'two']
    });
}
```

Can anyone please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

I think promisifying and using `Promise.All` is your best bet, something like:

```
var promisify = require('util').promisify;
var getUserWidgets1P = promisify(getUserWidgets1)
var getAllDefaultWidgetsP = promisify(getAllDefaultWidgetsP );
Promise.all([
  getUserWidgets1P(query)
  getAllDefaultWidgetsP(query)
]).then(function(results){
  results[0] // 1st promise result
  results[1] // 2nd promise result
}).catch(function(err){
  console.log('if any error:',err);
})
```

Or, convert your callback functions to a promise based function directly, if you haven't already used them elsewhere in your code and don't need backwards compatibility, i.e.

```
function getUserWidgets1(query) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    var finalResult = {};
    var userPreferencesDatabaseObject = dbs.userpreferencedbstart("User Preferences: get Widgets ");
    userPreferencesDbHelper.getUserWidgets(userPreferencesDatabaseObject, query, function(result, err){
        dbs.userpreferencedbstop
        (userPreferencesDatabaseObject, 
            "getUserWidgets");
        if(err){
            logger.error(err);
            reject(err);
        }else {
            finalResult.data = result.rows;
            resolve(finalResult);
        }
    });
  });
}
```